# Run Javascript function if page load, scroll and resize

Tags: javascript

I have a question about running a Javascript function if the page is loaded, on scrolling and on resizing.

I created a function in Javascript and I will use this by one simple call like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dataView('.result');
</script>
```

What I don't want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    dataView('.result');
});

window.addEventListener("onload", function(){
    dataView('.result');
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    dataView('.result');
});
</script>
```

What is a good solution to program a function with this options?

Comment: You're going to have to call these commands. The only room for optimization I see (apart from using jQuery for instance) is to make the `'.result'` parameter dynamic.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("onload"` <-- why is there "on"?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to bind all the events separately. You can make it an array.

```
function dView(){
  dataView('.result');
}

["load", "resize", "scroll"].forEach(function (evt) {
  window.addEventListener(evt, dView);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function within a function and call this function in the event handlers.
Call the main function on the pages what you want.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dataview(){
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
      thedata();
  });
  
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
      thedata();    
  });
  
  window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
      thedata();
  });
  
  function thedata(){
    alert('For example');
  }
}
</script>
```

Call the function on the pages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dataview();
</script>
```